# 'with' structure type and exception handling

Tags: ponylang

The following code does not compile because the compiler believes that the type of the 'with' expression is (U8 | None) although as I don't see how it may happen that it's body will get to None

```
class Disposable
  new create() => None
  fun dispose() => None
  fun value(): U8 => 42

primitive TestWith
  fun apply(): U8  =>
    with d = Disposable do 
      d.value()
    end
```

But if I add the 'else' section to the 'with' - everything gets fine with types. But the compiler complains that "try expression never results in an error"

```
primitive TestWith
  fun apply(): U8  =>
    with d = Disposable do 
      d.value()
    else
      0
    end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`with` block makes sure the object is disposed even when nested code reports error. In your case the body `d.value()` does not produce error. You don't need `with` statement in this case.

You have two options to make your code compile:

a) call `dispose()` directly (doesn't look elegant at all):

```
class Disposable
  new create() => None
  fun dispose() => None
  fun value(): U8 => 42

primitive TestWith
  fun apply(): U8  =>
    let d = Disposable
    let result = d.value()
    d.dispose() // dispose manually
    result
```

b) have a partial function inside `with` body:

```
class Disposable
  new create() => None
  fun dispose() => None
  fun value(): U8? => error // partial function

primitive TestWith
  fun apply(): U8  =>
    with d = Disposable do 
      d.value() // possible failure here
    end
```

Comment: The second example will not compile.  The compiler will say: 'function body isn't the result type', assuming that function body type is (U8 | None). It has been discussed at IRC channel, and the conclusion is that it's a bug. I'm about to fill a bug report on this topic.